# Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY installing Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, npm

When I run:

```
source <(curl -sL https://cdn.learnenough.com/heroku_install)
```

to install Heroku on the cloud9 IDE I get this error:

```
p GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1430:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:1029:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:521:13)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:418:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "n" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/environment
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/environment/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
sudo: n: command not found
bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
function
```

I got this error after trying to install Heroku to deploy my Ruby on Rails application done with the AWS Cloud9 IDE.
I didn't find any suitable fix for this, please help!

Comment: OK, I think it's fixed. Something had broken in the Node ecosystem that caused the script to fail. Luckily, Heroku has released an updated standalone version of its CLI, so I've switched to that in the installation program:

`source <(curl -sL https://cdn.learnenough.com/heroku_install)`

Please let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for not answering @mhartl, that solved my problem. Thank you, I was following your tutorial.